# how to search a particular string from an html page stored in local directory in python?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a list of web pages saved on desktop and I want to find out whether a particular word is there in those web pages stored locally and give the list of web pages having that word out of those. How to do this ? I have used os directory to retrieve the names of those html pages now how to find string from them, please help

Answer (score -1):

Do you need to find a word in the ulr? Then a program like notapad++ would be very good and then use the search feature ctrl+F on windows and command+F on mac i belive. And the just search for the word you need